# Replacing text in PDF using PDFNetPython3 - Not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a function which is supposed to replace a text in a PDF file. There are no errors shown however the text is not getting replaced in the output file. It is same as that of the input file. What could be wrong?

```
import sys
from PDFNetPython3 import *

input_path = "D:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\"
output_path = "D:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\"            

def changeText():
        PDFNet.Initialize()
        doc = PDFDoc(input_path + "input.pdf")
        doc.InitSecurityHandler()
        replacer = ContentReplacer()
        page = doc.GetPage(1)
        replacer.AddString("Old_content","New_content")
        replacer.Process(page)
        doc.Save(output_path +"sample.pdf", SDFDoc.e_linearized)
        doc.Close()
        print("File Saved")

changeText()
```

Comment: Don't you need to call RefreshFieldAppearances() on the doc after updating it? I use GetField(field_name),SetValue(value) instead of ContentReplacer(), but I assume both do the same.

Answer (score 0):

PDFNetPython3 is only supported to python 3.8. What version of python are you running?

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.